# Objective C getter method not working for property

Tags: objective-c, class, properties

I was playing around with objective C. This is my code for a class I wrote , arithmetic.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface arithmetic : NSObject
@property  int cur;


-(id)initWithNumber:(int)number;
@end




@implementation arithmetic
@synthesize cur;
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        NSLog(@"Yo, all works :D ");
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithNumber:(int)num{

    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        [self setCur:8]  ;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Note the @property int cur. I was excepting objective c to create a setCur and a getCur method as accessors and mutators for my class. However, when I run this:

```
arithmetic *test = [[arithmetic alloc] initWithNumber:89];
        [test setCur:534];
        NSLog("%i",[test getCur ]);
```

The first two lines work. But the last line says 
No visible interface for arithmetic declares the selector 'getCur'

What is the problem ?

Comment: The getter is just `cur`.

Comment: that is it ? i thought it would make sense to have a set and a get. The docs say. The method used to set the value (the setter method) starts with the word “set” and then uses the capitalized property name.
The setter method for a property called firstName will be called setFirstName:

Comment: yes, that is it. You are right about how the setter is named, just assumed wrong about the getter. They could have gone either way, maybe the unadorned name suiting the dot syntax helped the choice.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you declare like this in your @implementation:

```
@synthesize cur;
```

it will create getter

```
-(int)cur {
  return _cur;
}
```

and also it will create a setter

```
-(void)setCur:(int)newCur {
  _cur = newCur;
}
```

In summary, Objective-C getter/setter is having a pattern of propery/setPropery respectively, unlike Java that uses getProperty/setProperty.

And Objective-C getter/setter is accessed via dot(.) notation. For example

```
int x = obj.cur;
obj.cur = 100;
```